# Uncaught Sys.ArgumentNullException: Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: panelsCreated[1]

Tags: 2010, javascript, ajax, updatepanel

I am using JavaScript to pull events for the current day of the week. I am leveraging [SP.Services](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) to do this. The problem I am having seems to be the same that a lot of others have experienced building AJAX enabled webparts. I have seen solutions instructing to enable `PartialRendering` to remedy this. The issue I am facing is that this a complete JS solution so I do not have access to server-side settings, so I'm wondering if there is a way to solve this client side.

This seems to be a solvable client-side because its just an issue of a control in the ribbon not being properly initialized in the browser.

** SP JS causing error **

```
Sys.WebForms.PageLoadedEventArgs = function Sys$WebForms$PageLoadedEventArgs(panelsUpdated, panelsCreated, dataItems) {
/// <summary locid="M:J#Sys.WebForms.PageLoadedEventArgs.#ctor" />
/// <param name="panelsUpdated" type="Array"></param>
/// <param name="panelsCreated" type="Array"></param>
/// <param name="dataItems" type="Object" mayBeNull="true"></param>
var e = Function._validateParams(arguments, [
    {name: "panelsUpdated", type: Array},
    {name: "panelsCreated", type: Array},
    {name: "dataItems", type: Object, mayBeNull: true}
]);
if (e) throw e; //Error thrown here
Sys.WebForms.PageLoadedEventArgs.initializeBase(this);
this._panelsUpdated = panelsUpdated;
this._panelsCreated = panelsCreated;
this._dataItems = dataItems || new Object();
}
```

**Server Side Solution**

[EnablePartialRendering](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/26778)

[ScriptMode=Release](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/503174/MicrosoftplusJScriptplusruntimepluserror-aplusSys)

[ScriptMode=Release (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792923/asp-net-can-not-debug-this-problem-sys-argumentnullexception-value-cannot-be)

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the post-back events, one of the validation seems to be failed on your page before the event happens, i recommend to identify it and try fixing it.